# How to decide which aerodromes should have Electronic Terrain and Obstacle Data?

Tags: airport, terminology

1. What is the meaning of "aerodrome that is regularly used in international civil aviation"?

Is there any explanation or reference material in support of Aeronautical Information System (AIS)?

2. I found several things in Eurocontrol document but there is no exact explanation and solution to decide which aerodromes should have Electronic Terrain and Obstacle database.

Comment: you need to check what is an aerodrome first which is basically small airport https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerodrome

Comment: @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz *Aerodrome* does not mean "small airport"; it is a general term covering everything from a tiny grass strip to the largest international airports.

Comment: @J.Hougaard that's true, shame on me i did not finished my sentence correctly. It was supposed to be "small airport to largest". At least that was what i had in my mind. shall i delete it or i could edit it, maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, i should say, i'm looking for definition about "regularly used aerodromes in international civil aviation". This is a standard of ICAO that is key to select which aerodromes must have electronic terrain and obstacle database.                                            reference here: "From 12 November 2015, AT AERODROMES REGULARLY USED BY INTERNATIONAL CIVIL AVIATION, electronic obstacle data shall be provided for all obstacles within Area 2 that are assessed as being a hazard to air navigation.” ICAO ANNEX-15.

Answer (score 1):

An [aerodrome or airdrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerodrome) is a location from which aircraft flight operations take place, regardless of whether they involve cargo, passengers, or military. Aerodromes include small general aviation airfields, large commercial airports, and military airbases.

> An [airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airport) is an aerodrome with extended facilities, mostly for commercial air transport. Airports often have facilities to store and maintain aircraft, and a control tower. An airport consists of a landing area, which comprises an aerially accessible open space including at least one operationally active surface such as a runway for a plane to take off or a helipad, and often includes adjacent utility buildings such as control towers, hangars and terminals. Larger airports may have fixed-base operator services, airport aprons, taxiway bridges, air traffic control centers, passenger facilities such as restaurants and lounges, and emergency services.

With this definitions of aerodrome and airport from Wikipedia, we understand that all airports are aerodrome but not all aerodromes are airport i.e. **airport is a subset of an aerodrome**.

The [Civil Aviation Safety Authority under CASR part 139](https://www.casa.gov.au/aerodromes/standard-page/aerodrome-categories-under-casr-part-139) classifies the Aerodrome into below categories:

1. Certified Aerodromes
2. Registered Aerodromes
3. Other Aerodromes - more than 9 but not more than 30 passengers
4. Other Aerodromes - operations under proposed CASR part 135

Answer (score 1):

ICAO Annex 14 defines aerodrome as:

> ***Aerodrome.*** A defined area on land or water (including any
>   buildings, installations, and equipment) intended to be used
>   either wholly or in part for the arrival, departure and
>   surface movement of aircraft.

The aerodrome may rarely see international traffic, but still can be considered to be "regularly used in international civil aviation," if it is used by dispatchers of other nations as a diversion airport in case of in-flight emergencies. Especially if we are considering ETOPS, said airport by agreements would have to be able to accept such traffic and have facilities and equipment ready for it.

---

About the **Electronic Terrain and Obstacle Data** (eTOD), from [SKYbrary.aero](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Electronic_Terrain_and_Obstacle_Data_(eTOD)):

> The States are required to ensure the availability of electronic TOD, in accordance with stringent numerical requirements established for four distinct Areas of the State territory. These areas are:
>
> - Area 1: the entire territory of a State;
> - Area 2: terminal control area (or limited to a 45-km radius – whichever is smaller), sub-divided in 4 smaller sections;
> - Area 3: aerodrome/heliport area: area that extends from the edges of the runway to 90 m from the runway centre line and for all other parts of aerodrome/heliport movement areas, 50 m from the edges of the defined areas;
> - Area 4: Category II or III operations area (restricted to those runways intended for Category II or III precision approaches): the width of the area shall be 60 m on either side of the extended runway centre line while the length shall be 900 m from the runway threshold measured along the extended runway centre line.

The manual is [here](http://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/publication/files/20120305-etodguidance_-v2.pdf).

Comment: "From 12 November 2015, AT AERODROMES REGULARLY USED BY INTERNATIONAL CIVIL AVIATION, electronic obstacle data shall be provided for all obstacles within Area 2 that are assessed as being a hazard to air navigation.” in the chapter 5 Eurocontrol document, they tried to solve what the   AERODROMES REGULARLY USED BY INTERNATIONAL CIVIL AVIATION are. But there is no solution there. They made decision for Eurocontrol, not for ICAO, Usually, i'm looking official explanation of ICAO