# Can you operate regular commercial flights from an airport that is uncharted and not in the national AIP?

Tags: regulations, aeronautical-charts, international

Is it possible to operate regular, commercial flights from an airport (aerodrome) that is not in the national AIP, and for which there are no charts, maps, terrain information, obstacle information, NOTAMs etc.?

Here in Mongolia there are 23 airports listed in the AIP ([ETOD](https://gis.icao.int/icaoetod/Gilbertstudyfinaldraft.pdf) is already collected and published for free) but there is discussion about removing all of them except [Chinggis Khaan International Airport (ZMUB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinggis_Khaan_International_Airport). That means, there would be no information available about those airports. Would they still be usable for flight operations?

(Related to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/42412/62).)

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. Are you asking if it's possible to operate regular flights from uncharted airports? The short answer is probably yes for private flights in light aircraft and no for larger aircraft and commercial flights: apart from practical navigation and flying issues, regulations and insurance companies might not allow it. But I may be wrong, if you can give us more information or examples about the flights and airports then someone may have a good answer.

Comment: @Pondlife Yes, You have understood correctly as uncharted airports, Currently there are 23 official Aerodromes(domestic), and they have appropriate aeronautical charts according to Annex-4 ICAO, But what happens if omit/remove/delete them from AIP of Mongolia.

Comment: @Pondlife Reason is one member of audit team at my work is saying like: "From 12 November 2015, AT AERODROMES REGULARLY USED BY INTERNATIONAL CIVIL AVIATION, electronic obstacle data shall be provided for all obstacles within Area 2 that are assessed as being a hazard to air navigation.” is meaning only Chinggis Khaan Airport but in the Annexes and Documents of ICAO, "AT AERODROMES REGULARLY USED BY INTERNATIONAL CIVIL AVIATION," phrase is frequently used for Aerodrome chart-ICAO, Instrument Approach Chart-ICAO ..... etc, this phrase is everywhere but not many people knows its meaning.

Comment: I've edited your question to include more information from your comments. If I got it wrong please reverse or edit again.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is yes, accordingto ICAO regulations.It depends though on  factors such as local aviation legislation. A PA34 departing from an uncharted private aerodrome weekly to deliver mail is a regular commercial flight. Nothing wrong there according to ICAO. Factors such as NOTAM terrain etc as you mention, ought to be dealt with under Rules of the Air Annex 2  as separate from other regulations such as on aerodromes Annex 6